# How To Configure Flutter/SDK to use a Specific Android Platform

Tags: android, flutter

I'm Setting up android Studio to use Flutter, but When I Run flutter doctor, I see that flutter is selecting the SDK Platform that is not Available, I have Android-17,25,27 but it selects Android-28 which is empty, how can I change it to use android-27 instead

```
virus@ask:~$ flutter doctor Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):  
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_NG)    
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)      
[✗] Android SDK file not found: /home/virus/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar.     
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)    
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.0)     
[!] Connected device ! No devices available ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I tried changing the directory name of Android-27 to Android-28 with no luck.

Comment: Please post terminal output as texts, not screenshot images

Comment: virus@ask:~$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_NG)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android SDK file not found:
      /home/virus/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.0)
[!] Connected device                           
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Answer (score 1):

Select in the menu
File -> Project Structure -> Project (in the left pane) -> Project SDK -> select the wanted SDK (in your case 27)

If you are not able to see the project structure tab
just go to View-> Tool Windows and add structure

Then double press the shift key on your keyboard and write `invalidate cache/restart` and confirm that you want to invalidate the cache/restart studio.

If it doesn't work try to run in the base folder of your project  `flutter config --android-sdk $sdk/path`

Comment: Will that fix the issue of flutter doctor??

Comment: I tried it but it still looking from folder android-28

Comment: Try to double click the shift key write invalidate cache/restart and invalidate/restart studio